# Does Pavan Mukta Asana help releasing gastrointestinal gas?

Tags: physiology, alternative-medicine, physical-fitness, yoga

[Pavan Mukta Asana](http://www.santosha.com/pavana.html)

> As mentioned above, **practicing the purvana-mukta-asana will help to release gastrointestinal gas**. It is also improves other gastrointestinal problems like upset stomachs and constipation by stimulating the abdominal region.

Does this pose release the gasses if done as mentioned?

Comment: in other words you should fart when you do the exercise